# Importing modules from nested folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a folder structure like this

```
main_folder
|
|--done
|  |
|  |--test1
|  |--__init__.py
|
|---check.py
```

**__init__.py:**

```
class Tries(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Test"
```

**check.py:**

```
from done.test1 import Tries
Tries()
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-10953298e1df> in <module>()
----> 1 from done.test1 import Tries

ImportError: No module named done.test1
```

I am not able to import modules from the nested folder. Is there any way to do this.

**Edit:**

After Salva's answer I changed my structure like this

```
.
├── check.py
|--__init__.py(no content)
└── done
    ├── __init__.py(no content)
    └── test1
        └── __init__.py <-- this files contains your Tries class
```

Same error is thrown now also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a file `__init__.py` in each directory you want it to be considered a package so you need it in **both** directories:

```
.
├── check.py
└── done
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test1
        └── __init__.py <-- this files contains your Tries class
```

Comment: Do you have *.pyc files in your hierarchy? Try to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

In the following file/folder structure your code just works here:

```
.
├── check.py
└── done
    └── test1.py
```

When I run check.py it prints Test. I didn't use __init__.py though. What you described as __init__.py I made test1.py.

Comment: I tested it in Spyder, maybe it takes care of some stuff in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import package `done` first

```
import done
```

If it doesn't work, probably you are running script from different folder than you specified (in this case `main_folder`)

From logs it seems like you are using IPython, in this case try to add your folder as module path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/your/main_folder')
import done
```