# How to import file from a nested directory with django

Tags: python, django

I am building a django web application. For the code, I have a few helper functions I am trying to import, but django gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError.` This is my file structure

```
── stock_predictor
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── models_helper
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── arma.py
    │   ├── data_handler.py
    │   └── yahoo_stock_data.py
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   └── homepage.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Here the `models_helper` directory contains a list of files I want to import in the tasks.py file.
I tried adding the `__init__.py` file to the models_helper directory, but this does not solve the issue. I also tried adding the path to `sys.path`. That, too, does not seem to solve the problem. My imports in the tasks.py files are as follows.

```
from models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData
from models_helper.data_handler import DataHandler
from models_helper.arma import AlgoARMA
```

The error I get is as follows.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models_helper'
```

**NOTE:** This seems to be a django issue as I can import using `sys` and run the python script directly from the terminal.

These are the links I followed to get the code to work, but it does not.

1. [Importing modules from nested folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267962/importing-modules-from-nested-folder)
2. [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)
3. [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/50474562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the root is the directory just above the apps, so you import with the name of the app as first module name:

```
from stock_predictor.models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData
```

in modules in the application (`stock_predictor`), like for example `models.py`, `views.py`, `tasks.py`, etc. you can use a relative import like:

```
# for models.py, views.py, tasks.py, etc.

from .models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData
```

Comment: This works. Is there any way to ignore the root during the imports?

Comment: @Sashaank: personally I would not use relative imports,  but depending what the module is where you import from, you can use for example `from .models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData` in `models.py`, but then it thus depends *where* you make that import.

Comment: Do I need the `__init__.py` file in the `modules_helper` directory when I am importing like this `from stock_predictor.models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData`?

Comment: @Sashaank: normally you add an `__init__.py` to every directory that you want to use as a Python module yes (although you can alter that behavior with some meta-programming).

Answer (score 0):

You want to add import in task.py then it should like

**relative import**

```
from models_helper import YahooStockData
from models_helper import DataHandler
from models_helper import AlgoARMA
```

because **init****.py** shows that this is a package folder, you have to import from that package, here **models_helper** is a package, and **YahooStockData** is your import.

**absolute import**

```
import models_helper.yahoo_stock_data 
import models_helper.data_handler
import models_helper.arma
```

**Import from root**

```
from stock_predictor.models_helper.yahoo_stock_data import YahooStockData
from stock_predictor.models_helper.data_handler import DataHandler
from stock_predictor.models_helper.arma import AlgoARMA
```